# Oracle External Tables do not return data

Tags: oracle

for instance I have this file downloaded from wikipedia

https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pageviews/2018/2018-04/pageviews-20180407-130000.gz

After donwload and unzip I am trying to return the data using external tables, but no data is returned. I realized (or I guess) that the delimiter in the file is space char(' '). Here is my code :

```
    CREATE TABLE Funcionarios_Externa (
Campo1 VARCHAR2(4000)
,campo2 VARCHAR2(4000)
,campo3 VARCHAR2(4000)
,campo4 VARCHAR2(4000)
,campo5 VARCHAR2(4000)
) ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
DEFAULT DIRECTORY DADOS_LOGISTICA
ACCESS PARAMETERS (
RECORDS DELIMITED BY newline
READSIZE 200048576
SKIP 1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
)
LOCATION ('pageviews-20170301-000000')
) REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

I am not sure on what I am doing wrong. No errors, just the data is not returned.

Can someone help me ? Thanks in advance

[image]

This is the log file and no badfile is generated (I added the bad file clause in the script

```
Field Definitions for table FUNCIONARIOS_EXTERNA
  Record format DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
  Data in file has same endianness as the platform
  Rows with all null fields are accepted

  Fields in Data Source: 

    CAMPO1                          CHAR (4000)
      Terminated by " "
      Enclosed by """ and """
      Trim whitespace same as SQL Loader
    CAMPO2                          CHAR (4000)
      Terminated by " "
      Enclosed by """ and """
      Trim whitespace same as SQL Loader
    CAMPO3                          CHAR (4000)
      Terminated by " "
      Enclosed by """ and """
      Trim whitespace same as SQL Loader
    CAMPO4                          CHAR (4000)
      Terminated by " "
      Enclosed by """ and """
      Trim whitespace same as SQL Loader
    CAMPO5                          CHAR (4000)
      Terminated by " "
      Enclosed by """ and """
      Trim whitespace same as SQL Loader
```

Comment: Does the file `pageviews-20170301-000000` exist in whatever directory is specified by the directory object `DADOS_LOGISTICA`?

Comment: Is there anything in the logfile or badfile (same directory as the datafile)?

Comment: Yes, it exists and nothing in the log files, just the usual messages. I guess that the problem is something with the file, but I am not sure. I got 7 lines from the original file and saved as .rtf and it worked. Also I created a test.txt with 5 columns and space as delimter and it worked.

Comment: What about the .bad file? Anything in that?

Comment: I just added BADFILE DADOS_LOGISTICA:'BAD.bad' in the script and no bad file is generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the link with sample file to load, i observered that the files does not have comma separation..it have whitespacce seperation. I changed the file name to have a .txt just in case..
Then could create external table syntax as below using sql*developer ..

```
SET DEFINE OFF
--CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY Enter New Dir AS 'M:\extract';
--GRANT READ ON DIRECTORY Enter New Dir TO USER;
--GRANT WRITE ON DIRECTORY Enter New Dir TO USER;
--drop table vijay_ext3;
CREATE TABLE vijay_ext3 
( c1 VARCHAR2(300),
  c2 VARCHAR2(128),
  c3 NUMBER(3),
  c4 NUMBER(3))
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
  (  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
     DEFAULT DIRECTORY DB_DUMP_DIR
     ACCESS PARAMETERS 
       (records delimited BY '\n' 
           DB_DUMP_DIR:'pageviews.bad'
           DB_DUMP_DIR:'pageviews.discard'
           DB_DUMP_DIR:'pageviews.log'
           skip 1 
           fields terminated BY WHITESPACE
           OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' AND '"'
           lrtrim
           missing field VALUES are NULL
           ( c1 CHAR(4000),
             c2 CHAR(4000),
             c3 CHAR(4000),
             c4 CHAR(4000)
           )
       )
     LOCATION ('pageviews.txt')
  )
  REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;

select * from vijay_ext3 WHERE ROWNUM <= 100;
```

Comment: Fantastic. THANKS A LOT my friend

Answer (score 0):

If external tables works sometimes and not others , you are probably connecting to a RAC db.. -- To ensure you are connecting to the instance where the file is located, you need to add INSTANCE_NAME the tnsnames.ora. 
if you are using easyconnect, then you can add instance name as well.
Eg.
connect vijay/oracle@//10.0.10.101:1521/vijay/vijay1

connect username/password@//hostname:port/service_name/instance_name

If this is not a RAC instance, then clearly the issue is in DIRECTORY info as you are bond to have a bad file there or a Oracle error during select or create.

Comment: I am using locally, not RAC and the directory is right. I guess it is something with the file but I am not sure. Also in the log files only have the usual messages, no error messages. JUst do not return any data